# sh alternative to bash cp {file,file}

Tags: bash, sh, cp

In a script, if I put `#!/bin/bash` at the top, this will work fine:

`cp directory/{foo,bar} destination`

However, with sh, this will give the error 'no such file or directory'. In sh, is there another way to accomplish the same end goal with one command?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you've observed, not all shells support [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion).

#### Way 1: Two separate paths (i.e., writing the prefix twice)

If your goal is really just to do it in one command, a simple way is:

```bash
cp directory/file1 directory/file2 destination
```

The [`cp`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/cp.1.html) command supports multiple source arguments followed by a destination argument. In fact, that's what's happening with the command that works for you in Bash. Bash performs brace expansion, which converts the command you've been using into the one shown above. That is, when you run `cp directory/{file1,file2} destination` in Bash, the `cp` command never sees any curly braces.

A command like that is simple and easy to understand. I suggest considering it.

#### Way 2: A variable for the prefix

But if your goal is to avoid *repeating* yourself, then you might prefer not to do it that way, especially if `directory` is actually a long path. After all, if you have to edit the path later in the script, you'd have to make changes to both occurrences.

You can store `directory` (or whatever, presumably longer path that is) in a [shell variable](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05):

```bash
dir='directory'
cp "$dir/file1" "$dir/file2" destination
```

`$dir` is [parameter expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02). The shell replaces it with the value held in the variable `dir`. When using parameter expansion, you [**should not omit**](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) the [double quotes](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02_03)--[except in the rare case](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells) that you want [field splitting](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_05) and [globbing](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_06) to be performed. (This applies to Bash as well.)

That's two commands, but if your actual goal is to avoid repeating yourself, that may be what you want. You could write

```bash
dir='directory'; cp "$dir/file1" "$dir/file2" destination
```

to make it "one command," but that's no shorter and it's a bit less readable.

(Note that you cannot simply remove the `;` there. The result of doing would be a well-formed command, but it would not do what you want. It would run the `cp` command, passing an an [environment variable](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) called `dir` with the value `directory` into the `cp` command's environment. Since it is *the shell* and not the `cp` command, that expands `dir`, this would not work.)

#### Way 3: `cd`ig to the prefix

If your script isn't doing anything else after performing this operation, or it doesn't matter what the current directory is for subsequent commands, then *if `destination` is an [absolute path](http://foldoc.org/absolute%2Bpath)*, you can use:

```bash
cd directory
cp file1 file2 destination
```

But I don't recommend that for scripting unless your script performs subsequent actions that benefit from being run from that directory, or can be more tersely or simply written when they are run from that directory. Except when the directory a script is run from is *meaningful* to the purpose of the script, relying on it can make the script harder to reason about; furthermore, if the `cd` command succeeds but the `cp` command fails, the resulting error messages may be less than fully illuminating. Instead, I mention the technique of `cd`ing to the source directory because it is a useful pattern for *interactive* shell use.

(As [Hannu pointed out](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1206121/sh-alternative-to-bash-cp-file-file/1206124?noredirect=1#comment2023906_1206124), you can [enclose any number of commands together inside `(` `)`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04) to run them in a [subshell](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/SubShell), and changes to the shell environment, including the effect of `cd`, will not persist after the command has run. This is a widely useful technique, and it was a substantial omission that I had not mentioned it. Note, however, that this does not mitigate any problems relating to having a [relative path](http://foldoc.org/relative%2Bpath) for `destination`.)

Note that if the `cd` command fails, the other commands will still typically run. This could copy different files you don't want copied (if there are other files with the same names in the directory the script was running from) or producing confusing error messages. So you may prefer:

```bash
cd directory && cp file1 file2 destination
```

The `&&` causes the second command to run [only if the first command succeeded](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_03). Note that that still does not undo the effect of running the first command. After the whole thing runs, you'll still be in `directory`, unless you ran it in a subshell with `(` `)`.

Comment: Thank you for the extensive answer, the goal is indeed to not repeat myself rather than explicitly doing it in 'one command'.

Comment: `Bash` supports "subshells", dunno if that exists is `sh` -> to launch one, use parentheses as in `( cd directory && cp file1 file2 destination )` - the cd and copy won't affect the shell you launch it from. ref: ` man bash | less -ip "compound commands" ` .

Comment: @Hannu Yes, this is a good point, and all [POSIX compatible shells](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04) -- including whatever shell provides `sh`, which in Ubuntu is `dash` -- do support the `(` `)` syntax for running commands in a subshell.

Comment: For this answer it doesn't really matter, but the files do not necessarily have such similar file names like `{file1,file2}`. could be `{foo,bar}` just as well.

Answer (score 4):

Edit 1: After the question was modified the first alternative is no longer valid and the second alternative is modified 'file1 file2' --> 'foo bar' and extended with extra examples.

---

<s>It works for me in `sh` with</s>

```
cp directory/file[12] destination
```

and it should work for you too.

A more advanced alternative is a for loop

```
for i in foo bar;do cp directory/"$i" destination;done
```

This is easy to extend for example to

```
for i in foo bar more files;do cp directory/"$i" destination;done
```

or

```
for i in dir1/foo* /dir2/bar*;do cp "$i" destination;done
```

or

```
for i in dir1/* /dir2/*;do cp "$i" destination;done
```

---

Edit 2: Instead of advanced constructs using `cp` it is worthwhile to learn and start using **`rsync`**, which is a tool with a lot of built-in features to copy locally or via a network and specifying what to copy.

See `man rsync`

Comment: Do these options work if the files don't have such similar names, or if it is one file and one directory with differing names?

Comment: The first alternative needs similar names. The second 'more advanced alternative` can have any names (and any nunber of names even with wildcards) instesd of 'file1 file2' in the for cormmand.